# Custom UIViewController viewDidUnload never gets called

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom UIViewController subclass that handles all the view initialization by itself (it doesn't use nib). There is also another UIViewController subclass loaded from nib. Both are contained by UITabBarController.
When a memory warning comes, the first controller does receive notification, but viewDidUnload doesn't get called. The second controller also receives notification and it's viewDidUnload does get called.
I checked in didReceiveMemoryWarning, self.isViewLoaded is TRUE and self.view.superview is null.
Both controllers (their tabs) are invisible at the time the notification appears.

Is there something special a custom view controller should do to be unloaded in a result of memory warnings?

Comment: AFAIK, It is entirely up to the os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are subclassing `UIViewContoller` and you do not initialize it from a NIB, you need to subclass the `-loadView` method. Otherwise iOS assumes that the view cannot be unloaded / reloaded.

It would be sufficient to just add the following to your implementation:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
}
```

I will try to find a documentation quote for that.

[The documentation is unfortunately not very clear on this matter.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)

Comment: Should not call [super loadView] in the custom loadView method.  Code like below: self.view = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame]autorelease];    //  this is noted by apple in the document quoted above

Comment: This is not a custom load method, but simply and implementation to let the Framework know that this view can be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the documentation on the View Controller Lifecycle. Specifically, check out the section on what happens when the memory warning is received. If your custom view controller's view is the view on screen, the OS will not attempt to release this view. Is this view on screen when you're getting the memory warning? In the simulator, navigate to the nib-loaded view and simulate a memory warning, see if your custom view gets released then. Also, see if viewWillUnload is being called. And make sure that in any of these methods that you're overriding that you call super.

Comment: He did say "Both controllers (their tabs) are invisible at the time the notification appears." which is what makes this question interesting....

Comment: Well, not the clearest question. I can have a view controller in a tab bar controller and hide the tab bar. That, to me, would be the same as saying "hide the tabs". My tabs are hidden, sure, but my view is still on screen. The tab bar controller is just a controller of controllers.